# Spark with divide and conquer

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I'm learning Spark and trying to process some huge dataset. I don't understand why I don't see decrease in stage completion times with following strategy (pseudo):

```
data = sc.textFile(dataset).cache()

while True:
    data.count()
    y = data.map(...).reduce(...)
    data = data.filter(lambda x: x < y).persist()
```

So idea is to pick y so that it most of the time ~halves the data. But for some reason it looks like all the data is always processed again on each count().

Is this some kind of an anti-pattern? How I'm supposed to do this with Spark?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is an anti-pattern.

`map`, same as most, but not all, of the distributed primitives in Spark, is pretty much  by definition a divide and conquer approach. You take the data, you compute splits, and transparently distribute computing of individual splits over the cluster.

Trying to further divide this process, using high level API, makes no sense at all. At best it will provide no benefits at all, at worst it will incur the cost of multiple data scans, caching and spills.

Answer (score 0):

Spark is lazily evaluated so in the `for` or `while` loop above each call to `data.filter` does not sequentially return the data but instead sequentially returns `Spark` calls to be executed later. All these calls get aggregated and then executed simultaneously when you do something later.

In particular, results remain unevaluated and merely represented until a Spark Action gets called. Past a certain point the application can’t handle that many parallel tasks.

In a way we’re running into a conflict between two different representations: `conventional structured coding with its implicit (or at least implied) execution patterns and independent, distributed, lazily-evaluated Spark representations`.

Comment: However, there's call to persist after filter()... Is it supposed to compute it immediately? This is iterative algorithm, so I wonder how I'm supposed to program it as I need the result from previous calculation to proceed to next phase.

Comment: To avoid the anti pattern you can do the computation on the fly which will save the time of persisting, this is one approach, I can suggest you some other approaches if could share the exact data and problem.